# Wiki problem with anchor

Tags: wiki, anchor, redmine

I'm developing a project based on a wiki. One of its functionality is assigning anchors to heading (h1. h2.,etc) and I want to link a word to one of this anchors so when it's clicked the page automatically scrolls down to the correct heading. As it says on the help page the anchor should be used as following:

> Redmine assigns an anchor to each of those headings thus you can link to them with "#Heading", "#Subheading" and so forth.

And then adds:

> [[Guide#further-reading]] takes you to the anchor "further-reading". Headings get automatically assigned anchors so that you can refer to them

So I tried to use it by writing [[LBAW#Glossario]], or [[LBAW"#Glossario"]] or
[[LBAW#"Glossario"]]....none of them worked creating a new page each time instead of scrolling down as it should.
If anyone could give any advised I would be very much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It is more about how the redmine wiki is used.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and figured it out. The anchor link ("click me") format looks like:

[[your_wiki_pagename#the-anchor|click me]]

the link will bring you to wiki page ("your_wiki_pagename"):

h2. the anchor

You need to replace the space in anchor text with "-" (the anchor -> the-anchor).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it in the current demo of redmine and it works.  http://demo.redmine.org/projects/anewproject/wiki/Headers

Assume the following text on the page called Headers:

```
h1. Headers

some text

This link goes to [[Headers#header2]]

h2. header2

some 
more
lines
of
text
to
see
scrolling
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply...tried the suggestion (even copy paste) and didn't work on my wiki...tried in yours and was just fine...don't know why mine creates a new page.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exact name of the anchor which Redmine has added by looking at the page source, or inspecting the element using browser tools.

I had the same problem but I hadn't put the exact name in, using the same case. My heading was:

**DNS (moved to separate page)**

and so Redmine created an anchor like this:

```
<a href="#DNS-moved-to-separate-page" class="wiki-anchor">¶</a>
```

so I had to use the following link:

[[Server_Configuration#DNS-moved-to-separate-page]]

and that worked.